# Brand New Fridge - Low water pressure from dispenser

Tags: water, refrigerator, water-pressure

I just bought a brand new - Whirlpool French door fridge.  Water is coming out of the machine, and ice is being made... but... the water pressure from the fridge is slow.  House pressure is fine, sprinkler system is fine.

Yes - valve is all the way open, line isn't kinked, and filter is brand new with the fridge (delivered yesterday).

Suggestions?

Comment: What are you using as a companion? What makes you think the pressure is low? The fixtures in your house, your garden hose are fed by 1/2" - 3/4" pipe, where your fridge is fed by a 1/4" water line

Comment: Get a funnel that has the same opening size as your smallest hose.  Pour water through it and see how long it takes to fill a cup.  Compare to that.  The water dispensers in fridges are pretty slow.  They're slower than some drinking fountains.

Comment: The integrated filter slows down your flow. In fact, it has to; chemical filters require a certain amount of "contact time" and are deliberately designed to reduce flow rate to that which allows the stated filter properties to be true (e.g. chlorine removal, fluoride removal, etc.)

Comment: Not going to dignify this suggestion as an answer, but if you use a cheap, off brand replacement filter they tend to flow better (because they don't filter as much).

Comment: Good to know - about the filter!  It is producing enough to make ice, but the ounces it says it is dispensing isn't even remotely close to what comes out in the cup.

Comment: Could my water line be too long?  Would that make a difference? There is a LOT of tube (previous owners have it tied up with a string) and the water line and the fridge are pretty close together.

Comment: My whirlpool elite had to be calibrated before the measured oz were correct.